# Magento remove add to cart button by editing view.phtml

Tags: magento

I have three StoreViews for my Magento. I tried to remove "add to cart" by editing `view.phtml` in the following path:

```
app/design/frontend/default/your theme/template/catalog/product/
```

The link about how to do that is [here](http://unwittinglyrad.com/2012/03/21/disable-add-to-cart-for-certain-products/).

My issue is that "add to cart" in English StoreViews has been removed as I expected, but the "add to cart" button is still displayed in the other two views. I have cleaned the cache, and also restarted Apache.

How can I fix that? Do these three StoreViews use the same `view.phtml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turn on  [Template Path Hints](http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/08/04/magento-how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-and-inline-translation/) to make sure you have remove it from the correct location

Comment: Template Path Hints is really a good tool, and this is my first time to use it. But by using Template Path Hints, I can see that all my StoreViews "add to cart" come from the same path.

Comment: If they are pulling from the same path, then only 2 things could cause this issue. (1.) cache/full page cache custom module - which I dont think is the issue (2.) the tutorial that you link to above have use custom product attribute that set which product to remove add to cart from `if(($_product->getAttributeText('instore_only')) == "Yes")` let me see your logic. Your product may not configure correctly in all 3 scope

Comment: If you are doing something similarly to `$_product->getAttributeText('instore_only')` then try to do `print_r($_product->getAttributeText('instore_only'))` to see what the value is for each storeview

Comment: From the admin panel, I can see those three StoreViews share the default value of 'instore_only'. I did not set them separately. But to make sure I would like to try your solution to print it out. I am a beginner, could you please tell me more about where can I see the result from print_r($_product->getAttributeText('instore_only'))?

Comment: Add it to the same place you add your custom code above your 'if' statement (view.phtml)

Comment: I just tried your solution. I got positive feedback from the web page. I do not know why it do not go into “if”. The only reason I can see is that in English we use "Yes", in Danish we use "Ja". I will try to change if(($_product->getAttributeText('instore_only')) == "Yes") to if(($_product->getAttributeText('instore_only')) == "Ja").

Comment: Well, great. I think I got it with your help. We have to use different "Yes" in different languages. If I change "Yes" to "Ja". The Danish StoreViews works, and the English StoreViews does not work again. But I am confuse, the Attribute 'instore_only' I set is only two values "Yes/No". Why it judged different in different languages?

Comment: Try `<?php echo $this->__('Yes') ?>` if that print 'Ja' then do `if(($_product->getAttributeText('instore_only')) == $this->__('Yes'))`

Answer (score 1):

In System->Configuration->General->Design you are able to apply different templates to different websites and store views.

Look at the Themes section and change the `Current Configuration Scope` in the top left (above the left hand admin menu) to your different store views to see what templates, skins and layouts are being applied to the different store views.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. All my StoreViews are using the same templates, skins and layouts. I am sure about that.

Comment: OK, well what does following @R.S 's advice do.  What template is it pulling from?